# Why does my function sometimes not execute the document.body.innerHTML command?

Tags: javascript

I've made a function to output data from Google Maps using the Google API. The function is called to output from an array of places.

The problem is that sometimes it won't output the last document.body.innerHTML part which outputs the place's URL. If I remove the for loop which outputs the place's review aspects then the URL is always shown.

```
function printme(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  document.body.innerHTML += ('<br />'+ place.name + ' R: '+ place.rating);

  for (var i = 0, reviews; reviews = place.reviews[i]; i++) {

    for (var x = 0, aspectr; aspectr = reviews.aspects[x]; x++) {
      document.body.innerHTML += ('<br />'+'Aspect: ' + aspectr.type + ' ' + aspectr.rating);
    }

}

  document.body.innerHTML += ('<br />'+ '<a href = '+place.url+'>'+place.url+'</a>'+'<br />'); 
  }

  else {
    alert(status);
  }
}
```

I can't get my head around why that is.

Comment: Ah, I think I found the problem. It's probably when the places.reviews array doesn't have anything in it then it crashes. How can I make an if statement to only run the code when places.reviews has stuff in it? <if (places.reviews.length>0){}> doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I figured it out. I used the following and it works a charm:
if (typeof place.reviews !== 'undefined'){...rest of code...}

Comment: `reviews = place.reviews[i]` - `reviews` is a bad name to use for this variable. You should call this variable `review`, not `reviews`, because it is a *single* review: `review = place.reviews[i]`

Comment: Also you will find it very helpful to [learn how to use the JavaScript debugger](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). It will help you pinpoint problems like this, try out different expressions, look at your variables, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the following if statement around the code and it works find now:

```
if (typeof place.reviews !== 'undefined'){
```

Comment: You can simplify that to `if( place.reviews ) { ... }`